# Error while searching two tables using Laravel and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Error while searching two tables using Laravel and AJAX
Hello, I am developing a search field in my system and it needs to search data in two tables, but I can not in any way have tried all the tutorials and checked all the documentation, but I can not find the solution.
Always error 500 when processing the request by Jquery. I believe the error is in the controller responsible for the request.
Follow all the codes below and I thank you for your response.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/customers', 'HomeController@customers')->name('customers');
Route::get('/customers/action', 'HomeController@customersAction')->name('customers.action');
```

**HomeController**

```
    public function customers(Request $request)
{

    $data = DB::table('projects')
        ->join('projects_info', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_info.project_id')
        ->select('projects.*', 'projects_info.cpf')
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->paginate(3);

    $menuTasks['view_type'] = "overview";
     if ($request->ajax()) {
        return view('project.livepagination', compact('data'));
    }
    return view('customers', compact('data'), $menuTasks);
}

public function customersAction(Request $request)
{
if($request->ajax())
 {
  $output = '';
  $query = $request->get('query');
  if($query != '')
  {

    $data = DB::table('projects')
         ->join('projects_info', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_info.project_id')
         ->select('projects.title as title','projects.id as id', 'projects.privacy as privacy', 'projects.user_id as user_id', 'projects_info.cpf as cpf')
            ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('cpf', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('privacy', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('user_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

  }
  else
  {
   $data = DB::table('projects')
     ->join('projects_info', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_info.project_id')
     ->select('projects.*', 'projects_info.cpf')
     ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
     ->paginate(3);
  }

  $total_row = $data->count();
  if($total_row > 0)
  {

   foreach($data as $row)
   {
    $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
     <td>'.$row.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->privacy.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->user_id.'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $output = '
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="5">Nenhum cadastro encontrado.</td>
   </tr>
   ';
  }
  $data = array(
   'table_data'  => $output,
   'total_data'  => $total_row
  );

  echo json_encode($data);
 }
}
```

**Customer.blade**

```
<div id="tag_container">
        @include('project.livepagination')
</div>
```

**customer.blade (jquery-ajax)**

```
//Pagination
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            }else{
                getData(page);
            }
        }
    });

$(document).ready(function()
{
     $(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
        var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
        getData(page);
    });
});

function getData(page){
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '?page=' + page,
            type: "get",
            datatype: "html"
        })
        .done(function(data)
        {
            $("#tag_container").empty().html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
              alert('Sem resposta do servidor!');
        });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function() {
$query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if ($query) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('customers.action') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            'query': $query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
        }
    });
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('customers.action') }}",
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            'query': $query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
        }
    });
}});
```

**Project.livepagination**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Busca..."/>
    </div>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Nome</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>CPF</th>
     <th>Privacy</th>
     <th>User_id</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    @foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row->title}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->cpf}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->privacy}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->user_id}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
   </tbody>
  </table>
{!! $data->links() !!} 
</div>
```

**Models/Project**

```
public function projects_info() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\ProjectsInfo', 'id');
}
```

**Models/ProjectInfo**

```
public function projects() {
return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
```

Are there all the codes that are part of the search system using AJAX, I hope to have help finding this error.

Comment: First of all, 500 errors are throwed by the server, not by ajax;Can you show the error returned by this server ? Thank you.

Comment: I checked the whole log and in another site I had a help that made me find the error, below is the solution of the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code for those who need it:

**HomeController**

```
public function customersAction(Request $request)
{
if($request->ajax())
 {
  $output = '';
  $query = $request->get('query');
  if($query != '')
  {


    $data = DB::table('projects')
         ->join('projects_info', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_info.project_id')
          ->select('projects.title as title', 'projects.id as id', 'projects.privacy as privacy', 'projects.user_id as user_id', 'projects_info.cpf as cpf', 'projects_info.project_id as project_id')
            ->where('title', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('cpf', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('project_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('privacy', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orWhere('user_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

  }
  else
  {
   $data = DB::table('projects')
     ->join('projects_info', 'projects.id', '=', 'projects_info.project_id')
     ->select('projects.title as title', 'projects.id as id', 'projects.privacy as privacy', 'projects.user_id as user_id', 'projects_info.cpf as cpf', 'projects_info.project_id as project_id')
     ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
     ->paginate(3);
  }

  $total_row = $data->count();
  if($total_row > 0)
  {

   foreach($data as $row)
   {
    $output .= '
    <tr>
     <td>'.$row->title.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->cpf.'</td> 
    <td>'.$row->project_id.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->privacy.'</td>
     <td>'.$row->user_id.'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $output = '
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="5">Nenhum cadastro encontrado.</td>
   </tr>
   ';
  }
  $data = array(
   'table_data'  => $output,
   'total_data'  => $total_row
  );

  echo json_encode($data);
 }
}
```